# Is one-insert-multi-read list safe without lock?

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, synchronization

I have a problem about synchronization between threads. I know the normal synchronization method and lock-free list. But I have a strange (maybe) idea.

I have a normal singly list in C language, linked by `next` pointer.

There is only 1 thread who just insert items into this list, but never delete items. The way to add item:

```
new_item->next = list_head;
list_head = new_item;
```

There are some other threads who just traverse this list (read only).

There is no lock at all.

I think that this should be safe, because the read-only-threads will never get an invalid pointer.
Am I right?

I do not know how to search this on internet. What I get is all about lock-free list by CAS or something. So I ask it here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add some language tag.

Comment: Also, note that CAS is needed only if you have multiple writers, which is not your case.

Comment: @DanielLangr, thanks, I have added `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the language and data types, but generally, that could be a **data race** (undefined behavior in C++), since one thread may modify `list_head` and other threads may read it at the same time.

If these reads/writes are *atomic*, then there is no data race. To my best knowledge, on x86 architecture, reads and writes are atomic automatically. But this may not hold for other architectures.

Moreover, *reordering* issues may broke things here, that's what *memory fences* are for, which are typically generated by the compiler when (sequentially consistent) atomic operations are involved. You update values of 2 pointers and, e.g., in C++ with *relaxed memory ordering*, threads are permitted to "see" these updates in a different order (generally due to compiler optimizations, out-of-order execution, CPU store buffers, etc.). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order for more details.

In C++11, you need `std::atomic` to ensure atomic operations on `list_head`. With OpenMP, there is `#pragma atomic read/write (seq_cst)` directive.

Comment: Thanks. If the 2 pointer assignments are executed in the other order by compiler/CPU reordering when inserting items, the read threads may get an invalid pointer. I am not familiar with memory reordering, but I just take that my idea is not safe.

Comment: After some searching about memory reordering, I find that I can add [Compiler Barriers](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) to avoid compiler reordering.

Comment: @BingzhengWu Yes, but you need to avoid memory reordering as well. Do you have C11 compatible compiler? If yes, you can use http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic.